# Cronjob executed multiple times per minute

Tags: linux, cron, daemon

I have to maintain a pretty old Linux Server running on SLES 10, kernel 2.6.16 in a VMWare environment. Apart from the fact that it should be updated I have the following problem:

I noticed that cronjobs were executed multiple times in the same minute! So I set up a cronjob which looked like this:

`* * * * * date >> /tmp/test.log`

In this logfile I can see that 2-15 times in a day the job was executed several times in the same minute.

Examples:

```
Mon Apr  8 04:12:01 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 04:12:52 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 04:12:52 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 04:12:52 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 04:12:52 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 04:12:52 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 04:12:52 CEST 2019

Mon Apr  8 05:32:01 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 05:32:54 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 05:32:54 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 05:32:54 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 05:32:54 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 05:32:54 CEST 2019
Mon Apr  8 05:32:54 CEST 2019
```

I already checked that the cron daemon is running only once.

Does anyone have any idea what the reason for this might be?

Regards,
Till

Answer (score 0):

per this [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) it looks like one of your intervals needs to be */15 or similar.  With just asterisks it will run any time or all the time.  Note, I am not a linux user.

Comment: I think that 's not the cause. As you can check here https://crontab.guru/ it should work well. I also used that format many times in the past on other servers.